# storing dynamic strings

Tags: ios, swift, string, sorting, save

The task is as follows.

Сheck the string for the word (Player) and replace it with the name from the array; if there is another word (Player) in the string, then replace it with another name.
I can replace the name once, but how can I do this by replacing all the words (Player) in the string with different names?

Comment: add variables to your string like "@NAME@ must drink juice with @NAME@", replace @NAME@ with names from your array

Comment: If I save the strings in a text file, will this be good  practice or is it better to do something else?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @joakimDanielson I tried almost what was advised above. I saved the lines in a text file and substituted the names in variables. I do not ask you to write me a code. I want to find out if there is a more correct or better way to do this

Comment: Better than what? Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: better than storing lines in a text file and substituting variables

Comment: "placeholders", you are looking for "placeholders". You can either use "%@", and use `String(format:)`, custom placeholders `#HERE#`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `StringWithFormatter` , and use place holders `%@` to replace certian parts of strings.

Or another thing you can do is `appendAttributedString` . For this you have to seperate the string into differentParts.

If the below text is used

"Alex must drink juice with Nicole "

We can seperate it as 3 parts

1.Prefix (firstName)

2.PostFix (secondName)

3.The String(must drink juice with)

You have to initialize these as `AttributedStrings` or `MutableAttributedStrings` as you are changing the Strng value.Following that you can use,

```
    NSMutbableAttributedString prefixName = [[NSMutableAttributedString init] alloc];

    //assing the name1 value here either from a customString file or objects or however you want it passed

    NSMutableAttributedString String = [[NSMutableAttributedString initWithString:@"must drink juice with"];

    NSMutbableAttributedString posFixName = [[NSMutableAttributedString init] alloc];

    //assing the name2 value here either from a customString file or objects or however you want it passed

[prefixName appendAttributedString:String];
[String appendAttributedString:postFix];

     //this would result in Name1must drink juice withName2 , you will probably have to manage spacing if i remember right
```

Comment: Why use `NSAttributedString`? That's not in the question. Also, what happen if in another language, prefixName & postFixName should be reverted, etc. Here it's at the start & end, but could be in the middle, etC.

Comment: Regardless of the position you can still append the word using this , however like i stated using Placeholders and passing them as values from either plist or customstring file is the best approach . Obviously we can use variables and pass them as well